# cuDNN failed to initialize

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node conv2d_1/convolution}}]]
     [[norm_dense_1/Softmax/_3605]]
  (1) Unknown: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[{{node conv2d_1/convolution}}]]
```

This error was encountered when trying to run a project from Github.I have tried reinstalling all the programs from scratch in a new conda environment. Can't seem to figure out whats the problem.

GPU Zotac gtx 1070 ti

My current software installation is as follows:-

- Python 3.6
- Tensorflow GPU 1.15
- CUDA 10
- cuDNN 7.4

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24828#issuecomment-456195431
tried this?

Comment: @AlexanderRiedel Yes I tried but the problem persists

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have CUDA Toolkit 7.5
Please open a new session then just try to load tensorflow

Are you able to load tensorflow without any error? Make sure all the ddl cudard64_101.ddl
and others are loading.
If there are no issues with tensorflow then run the following

```
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```

Once done try running code again

Comment: I have had this error message when I have to many instances of a python program running that uses the gpu. I suspect it is due to contention for memory. Try closing all instances of python except the one you want to run.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same output. The problem for me was that i had accidentally set two different environment variables for cuda. The PATH had 2 locations for cuda folder and that caused the problem for me. Removing one of them solved the problem for me.